# Step Testing in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

while testing a step which is a chunk oriented processing that contains reader and writer using jobLauncherTestUtils.launchstep().

1.how to pass or set the job explorer while testing it as a single step?

**Step:**

```
    @Bean(name="step_name")
    public step step1(RepositoryItemReader<Person> perosnItemReader,
        FlatFileItemWriter<String> personItemWriter,
        TaskExecutor personTaskExecutor){
      return StepBuilderFactory
          .get("step_name")
          .listener(new listener())
          .<Person,String>Chunk(200)
          .reader(personItemReader)
          .writer(personItemWriter)
          .listener(new DateReadListener())
          .build();
    }
```

**Reader**:

```
@Bean(name="step_reader")
public RepositoryItemReader<Person> personItemReader(
    @Value("#jobParameters[id]}" String id){
  return new RepositoryItemReader<Person>()
        .name("step_reader")
        .repository(personDao)
        .methodName("getDetails")
        .arguments(id)
        .build();
}
```

**Writer**:

```
@Bean(name="step_writer")
public FlatFileItemWriter<String> personItemWriter(
    @Value("#{jobExecutionContext[person]}") Person person,
    @Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution.id}" long id,
    JobExplorer jobExplorer) {

    Foo foo = new 
    Foo(jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobId).getExecutionContext(),new 
    CurrentDate());
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder()
        .get("item_writer")
        .callback(foo)
        .build();
  }
```

**The Way i Tested It.**

```
ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext()
executionContext.put("person",Person);  
JobExecution jobExecution =              
    JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("step_name",jobparams,executionContext);
```

**Issue**

```
class Foo{
   Foo f = new Foo(JobExecution jobExection, Date date);
   Person person = (Person)jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("person");
}
```

Here,jobExecution returning **null** value.

ThanksInAdavnce

Answer (score 0):

> How can i check wheather reader returns the data successfully?

you don't need to test the whole step to check if the reader returns the data correctly. A unit test of the reader itself should be enough: create and open the reader, call `read` and assert on the result.

> 2.how to pass job execution id and job explorer to writer which takes both values as parameters?

Why would an item writer need a job execution and a job explorer? From your code, those are not used when creating the writer.

Comment: The step i am supposed to test contains the above reader and writer, i am testing that step with jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(stepname,<jobParam>,<executioncontext>). when it goes into writer the jobexplorer is being used to fetch the data from execution context.It works fine when testing as a whole job but not as a single step.

Comment: if your test context is managed by Spring (which I am expecting), then you can inject the job explorer and pass it to the writer.

Comment: Actually,I am a newbie to spring and spring batch it would be so helpful for me if you give an example or any link to a sample code.Thanks In Advance

Comment: you can find code examples of how to test a single step or a step-scoped component within a step in this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#testingIndividualSteps

Comment: I tried  what is shown in  documentation but i think it still require some add on to add, but i don`t know what is it.could you please help me